# Elastic Search get vs action get

Tags: java, elasticsearch, get

What is the difference between elastic search get vs action get?

Is it just that one exposes the exceptions where as the other one handles them itself?

All the usage examples with elastic search that I see (in Java) use actionGet, i.e

`SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet();`

Which one should I be using and when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FromThe official javaDocs of `actionGet()`

> Similar to {@link #get()}, just catching the {@link
>   InterruptedException} and throwing
>        * an {@link org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException} instead. Also catches
>        * {@link java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException} and throws the actual cause instead.

It just provides a wrapper over `Future#get()`, catches `InterruptedException, ExecutionException` and wraps them into `ElasticSearchException`

Also, you can directly use `client.prepareSearch().get()` instead of `client.prepareSearch().execute().actionGet()` . It internally does the same.

Comment: Thanks,  also wondering where did you find the javaDocs? I thought there was no official java docs? Or did you just decompile it into source files and look at the documentation there?

Comment: Yea.. I do have the source checked out and checked it there. :)